# Нужно ли защищать вектор инициализации (IV) при шифровании AES 128 CBC

Tags: безопасность, криптография, aes

Доброго времени суток.

Реализую шифрование AES 128 CBC. Информации в Интернете конкретно по этому режиму довольно мало, так что задаю вопрос сюда.

Нужно ли хранить вектор инициализации в защищенном месте? Получит ли злоумышленник преимущество, если ему будет доступен вектор инициализации? Можно ли его со спокойной душой запихнуть в конец шифруемого файла в открытом виде?

Comment: Не нужно. Более того, он обычно передаётся вместе с шифрограммой в самом начале.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализационный вектор передаётся в первом блоке в открытом виде. Основная задача инициализационного вектора - гарантировать, что один и тот же файл будет каждый раз шифроваться по-разному. Поэтому IV никак защищать не нужно.

[На соответствующей странице в Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) приведён пример шифрования картинки без IV в режиме ECB - несмотря на использование стойкого шифра сама структура файла вполне себе различима. Поэтому в реальной жизни IV и CBC/CTR используются всегда.

[Официальная спецификация CBC](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38a/final) находится на сайте NIST. Там ничего сложного, спецификация занимает полторы страницы. Плюс несколько страниц тестовых векторов. Кроме того, в этом же документе приведена спецификация режима CTR.

На многоядерхных процессорах режим CTR предпочительнее, так как позволяет шифровать блоки параллельно, а CBC строго последователен.